# $\mathbb{R}^S$ for finite and countable set $S$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For a finite and countable set $S$, what does $\mathbb{R}^S$ mean? It seems like it should mean something similar to the power set but I can't think of what this is. Also, I couldn't figure out how to search for an answer to this question!

Comment: In general, $\mathbb{R}^X$ can be seen as the set of functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Equivalently, this is the product of $|X|$ copies of $\mathbb{R}$ indexed by $X$.

Comment: You may also the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ written ${}^AB$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By $\mathbb{R}^S$, we typically mean the set of all functions $f:S \to \mathbb{R}$.  So what does a function from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$ look like?  If $S = \mathbb{N}$, then such an $f$ is just a sequence of points in $\mathbb{R}$.  That is, if we denote $f(n) := x_n$, then f corresponds uniquely with the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.  A similar result holds for finite S.  Notice that it's not quite the power set, because the sequence holds more information than just which elements are in it.  It holds the information of what order these points come in and how often they occur.

Edit: As per the comments, the word "order" here would only be referring to $S$ when it's a subset of some ordered set (think $\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: The word "order" is a little misleading here; if $S$ is not ordered to begin with, the "sequence" (function from $S$) does not magically create any ordering (and even if $S$ is ordered, it's still not obvious that it does anything like that if it is not injective, particularly if $S$ is not wellordered). It still contains more information than a set, of course.

Comment: True, I was thinking about subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ when I said that.  I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}^S$ is the set of function from $S$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

For example $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is the set of all sequences of real elements.